# Php Character Filter

Tags: php, filter, char, int, preg-match

i need a php filter for char. 
could not find it anywhere.

i have tried char, chars, chr etc.

i know i could have php filter only int if i do this

```
$int = int $_GET['INT'];
```

if input is 23#@$23fgd4 then output would only be 23234

i could not seem to find any document on php.net on this or here.
no, i do not want a preg-match approach.

also, is it recommended to use such an approach? is it save? highly hackable?

any replacement other then preg cause it tend to take a lot more resource.

Comment: Regex is the best solution for this, IMO. `cause it tend to take a lot more resource.` -- Did you benchmark this? If so, please share the results.

Comment: i was thinking of using it on a RPi which to said, like i'm running on a old p1. all i need it to do is handle up to 100 request every minute. also, i remenber using preg and it took a second longer alway. heard it do not have that issue now, but, could not figure out the command for preg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to cast type into string?

```
$int = (string) $_GET['INT'];
```

But I guess you want to leave only characters in your script, then it should be

```
$int = preg_replace('/\W+/','',$_GET['INT']);
```

And regular expressions don't take that much time. It's a myth of the past. It works even faster than some spaghetti workarounds.

Comment: int is an example, but do '/\W+/' leave string or int?

Comment: \w stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.
So, \W - is everything that isn't [A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: i see, so how do i only include A-Za-z without the 0-9?

Comment: $int = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i','',$_GET['INT']);